# <rich:fileUpload> component controls issues in RichFaces 4.3

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, richfaces

**Versions:**

- RichFaces: 4.3
- MyFaces: 2.1

**Problem:**

There are two issues with the `<rich:fileUpload>` component in v4.3 of RichFaces which work fine in v3.0:

1. The `autoclear="true"` attribute does not seem to be working. I have referred below two links (neither of which seem to say anything about `"autoclear"` attribute):

   - [answer1](https://community.jboss.org/message/57756#57756)
   - [answer2](https://community.jboss.org/message/615055#615055)
2. The stop button doesn't show up after file is uploaded using upload button.

**Code:**

```
<rich:fileUpload maxFilesQuantity="5" fileUploadListener="#{bean.uploadFile}" 
               deleteLabel="RemoveNow" addLabel="BrowseFiles" uploadLabel="AttachFile" autoclear="true">
                   <a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" execute="@none" render="filePanel" />
 </rich:fileUpload>
```

Answer (score 2):

Those things are not implemented in RF 4.

If you need to clear the list after upload you can do something like this:

```
<a4j:ajax event="uploadcomplete" 
    oncomplete="#{rich:component('fileUpload')}.clearButton.triggerHandler('click')" … />
```

Comment: Thanks @Makhiel a lot or your repply. I will try above approach and update the post after result. For "stop" button , is it not possible to implement by any means ?